# Why do algebraic curves have to involve polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

*I.e.*, why, when we talk about an *algebraic curve* $f(x, y) = 0$, do we *assume* that $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial?

Surely the analysis of a curve like $|\cos(z)|^2 = 1$ is not beyond the reach of mathematics -- let alone modern mathematics.  But results like Bézout's Theorem require the curves in question to be polynomial.  Is it that the extension to general analytic functions is too hard?

Or, on the other hand, is it too easy (*e.g*, do results for more general $f(x,y)$ follow easily from results for polynomial $f(x,y)$)?

Comment: Well, polynomials are nice because there's a UFD of them (assuming the coefficient ring is nice). That makes results like Bezout possible.

Comment: That's mainly because they have special properties as to their intersections.over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: It is just a way to classify them: algebraic or transcendental.  Just as we classify numbers as algebraic or transcendental.

Comment: A number is called algebraic if it is the root of a polynomial with rational coefficients. An algebraic curve is a natural extension of that definition.

Comment: It's merely a name for this class of equations which happen to be both useful and accessible. There is nothing confining you to the study of such equations.

Comment: Algebraic geometry is about the function field and the coordinate ring of the algebraic variety, not the underlying manifold. Compact complex manifolds are a related concepts, and many theorems try to connect the two. Your curve $|\cos(z)|^2=1$ is mostly a real manifold, much less interesting.

Comment: Many useful facts about algebraic varieties are realized by working with closed sets in projective spaces and a famous theorem  says that any reasonable such (for example, analytic manifolds) are automatically defined by polynomials.

Answer (score 8):

You can study any equation you want. There's tons of mathematics for studying all kinds of equations. Some tools work better for this bunch of equations, other tools work better for that other bunch of equations.

It just so happens that there is an incredibly rich and beautiful set of tools for studying solution sets of polynomial equations, and which (for the most part) apply only to solution sets of polynomial equations and not other kinds of equations. This collection of tools is known as *algebraic geometry*.

As for your title question, what shall we call the solution sets of equations defined by polynomials? As the study of polynomial equations has evolved over the last two millenia or so, a terminology has emerged: nowadays their solution sets are known as *algebraic varieties*, and in the case of $f(x,y)=0$ as *algebraic curves*.

So, the real and literal answer to your title questions is: That's the definition of algebraic curves.